# Java stack dump on docker gives error

Tags: java, docker

we are trying to create automatic thread dump for our application.

Essentially, this is the code that is supposed to do that.

```
// Attach to the VM.
        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(selfPid);
        HotSpotVirtualMachine hotSpotVm = (HotSpotVirtualMachine) vm;

        // Request a thread dump.
        try (InputStream inputStream = hotSpotVm.remoteDataDump()) {
            return ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
        }
```

It works locally, and on our VMs, but not for the applications running inside docker. 
Inside docker Java complains

> 18:03:29,778 ERROR HandlerExecutionChain:173 -
>   HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   sun.tools.attach.BsdVirtualMachine.getTempDir()Ljava/lang/String;
>           at sun.tools.attach.BsdVirtualMachine.getTempDir(Native Method)
>           at sun.tools.attach.BsdVirtualMachine.(BsdVirtualMachine.java:308)
>           at sun.tools.attach.BsdAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(BsdAttachProvider.java:63)
>           at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)

The thing is, it is a linux docker image, running on a Linux VM on Zen; cannot understand why it is using BsdVirtualMachine.

Comment: I have the same problem and it is weird how docker acts